# Copy Folder/File wiithout modifying attributes?

Tags: c#, powershell, copy

Is it possible to copy a file or a folder from one location to another without modifying its attribute data? For example if I have a folder on a network drive and it was created on 2/3/2007 and I want to copy it to my c: drive .. but leave the date/time stamp as 2/3/2007...is that possible?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if it is possible; however you can use the methods within [System.IO.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file_methods(loband).aspx) and [System.IO.Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory_methods(loband).aspx) to reset these attributes back to what they were originally.

Specifically the SetCreationTime and SetModificationTime methods will be of most value to you in this case.

Answer (score 5):

I did something as shown below:

```
 File.SetCreationTime(tgtFile, File.GetCreationTime(srcFile));
 File.SetLastAccessTime(tgtFile, File.GetLastAccessTime(srcFile));
 File.SetLastWriteTime(tgtFile, File.GetLastWriteTime(srcFile));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you copy a file, it will retain the **modified date**, however the **created date** will be changed. I doubt there will be an easy way to retain the created date.

Comment: Store it before copying and restore it afterwards :)

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=net-7.0

```
The attributes of the original file are retained in the copied file.
```