# VB.NET - Better way to copy file with attributes?

Tags: vb.net

This is for a sync software, so the modified date etc needs to be the same.

Currently I am using this code to copy the file and set the attributes, but slows the transfer loop around 50%.

**VB.NET**:

```
CurrentFileCreationDate = File.GetCreationTime(CurrentLocalFile).ToString   
CurrentFileLastAccess = File.GetLastAccessTime(CurrentLocalFile).ToString
CurrentFileLastWrite = File.GetLastWriteTime(CurrentLocalFile).ToString

File.Copy(CurrentLocalFile, CurrentServerFile)

File.SetCreationTime(CurrentServerFile, CurrentFileCreationDate)
File.SetLastAccessTime(CurrentServerFile, CurrentFileLastAccess)
File.SetLastWriteTime(CurrentServerFile, CurrentFileLastWrite)
```

Is this the best way of doing it? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050813/copy-folder-file-wiithout-modifying-attributes

Comment: @NinethSense Sorry but the answers there don't explain anything.

Comment: Because there is no good answer available than what you did already, I believe :)

Comment: @NinethSense Then that's alright :).

Comment: @NinethSense wouldn't happen to know how to detect if a file has been renamed / deleted? My sync software just makes duplicates since it sees it as a new file.

Comment: FileSystemWatcher - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @NinethSense Thanks, I found that also. Defiantly needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the only way to do it.