# exact copy of files and folders

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have a problem I can't copy the contents of a folder exactly, as these are normally altered during copying using the classic `IO.File.Copy` commands or with the `My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile` function by vb.net.

Is there a single file bit-to-bit copy method without altering file and folder attributes?

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050813/copy-folder-file-wiithout-modifying-attributes  and this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163831/copy-a-file-with-its-original-permissions

Comment: " as these are normally altered during copying" you might want to explain this

Comment: fixed by copying attributes. Thanks